# boost filesystem version 3 issue?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io

the example code on the boost website is not working. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Using-path-decomposition

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  path p (argv[1]);   // p reads clearer than argv[1] in the following code

  try
  {
    if (exists(p))    // does p actually exist?
    {
      if (is_regular_file(p))        // is p a regular file?   
        cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

      else if (is_directory(p))      // is p a directory?
      {
        cout << p << " is a directory containing:\n";

        typedef vector<path> vec;             // store paths,
        vec v;                                // so we can sort them later

        copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));

        sort(v.begin(), v.end());             // sort, since directory iteration
                                          // is not ordered on some file systems

        for (vec::const_iterator it (v.begin()); it != v.end(); ++it)
        {
          path fn = it->path().filename();   // extract the filename from the path
          v.push_back(fn);                   // push into vector for later sorting
        }
      }

      else
        cout << p << " exists, but is neither a regular file nor a directory\n";
    }
    else
      cout << p << " does not exist\n";
  }

  catch (const filesystem_error& ex)
  {
    cout << ex.what() << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

two error messages when compiled in visual studio 2010 for the line `path fn = it->path().filename();`

The first error is: `'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator` and the second error is: `left of '.filename' must have class/struct/union`

Also, when I mouse over path() it says: `class boost::filesystem3::path Error: typename not allowed`

Comment: can u post the URL where you found this code ?

Comment: example code here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html#Using-path-decomposition

Comment: There was a change in the boost filesystem at some point. The header would have included a #define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION, where the return type of boost::filesystem::path::filename() changed from boost version 2 to 3. I have some code with #if #else, and in version 3, call .string() to make both versions match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section (`for`'s body) is problematic:

```
  path fn = it->path().filename();   // extract the filename from the path
  v.push_back(fn);                   // push into vector for later sorting
```

1. `it` points to `path` objects, so I don't see why `path()` is called. Seems that it should be replaced with `it->filename()`
2. you push filenames at the end of the same vector, so after the loop you will have the vector containing the list of files **twice**, first with pathnames then just filenames.

**EDIT**: Looking at the original example I see that these are your modification. If you want to store filenames instead of printing them, define another vector  of `string` or `path` and store filenames in it, don't reuse the first one.  And removing the call to `path()` should solve the compilation problem.

**EDIT 2**: as a cute BTW, you can achieve both directory traversal and filename extraction in one pass using `std::transform` instead of `std::copy`:

```
struct fnameExtractor {  // functor
  string operator() (path& p) { return p.filename().string(); }
};

vector<string> vs;
vector<path> vp;
transform(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(vs),
          fnameExtractor());
```

Same using `mem_fun_ref` instead of `fnameExtractor` functor:

```
transform(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(vp),
          mem_fun_ref(&path::filename));
```

Comment: Yeah I probably should have mentioned that I modified it, but that is the code that they have just below the example: 
"The key difference between tut3.cpp and tut4.cpp is what happens in the directory iteration loop. We changed:

    `cout << " " << *it << '\n';` 
to:
`path fn = it->path().filename();       v.push_back(fn);`"

Comment: tried your edit 2 with the functor and I got this error message: `No suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::filesystem3::path" to "std::string" exists.`

Comment: to solve that put `return p.filename().string();` in the functor

Comment: @ladookie - right, I forgot that. I'll edit. Although I vaguely remember the doc saying that `path` defines implicit conversion to `std::string`...

Answer (score 0):

After you posted the link it seems that the code posted is working fine. But problem is introduced in the modified code in `for` loop. 1st problem is that, `path()` is a constructor. 2nd problem, I am not sure about [boost::path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp) contains any method as `filename()`. You can try,

```
path fn = (*it);
```